# Angular redirect with a click to another page

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, path, click

how do I redirect from clicking on the Firms word to another component page?
I tried with routerLink="/",[routerLink]="['/']".
In the app.module Routes are imported.
Also tried like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; import { Router } from '@angular/router'; @Component({   selector: 'app-home',   templateUrl: './home.component.html',   styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'] }) export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {   // Inject Router Dependency   constructor(private router: Router) { }   ngOnInit(): void { }
    this.router.navigate(['/insights']);   } }
```

This is my code:

```
 <div class="container">   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item"  
            *ngFor="let firm of firms | async">
            {{ firm.hash }} - {{ firm.name }}
          </div>
              <div class="list-group-item">
                <a href="http://google.com">
                  Create new
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `DOCUMENT` from `@angular/common`:

import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) { }

redirectToUrl(): void {
    this.document.location.href = 'https://google.com';
}
```

and in your html file:

```
<button mat-button (click)="redirectToUrl()">Create new</button>
```